# Missing step importing URL to GraphDB

Tags: rdf, graphdb, rdflib, owlready

A newbie in semantic web, here. I have built a knowledge graph, my concepts already have URIs. However, my predicates do not have URIs and I created a vocabulary of my predicates - which is a ttl file - with owlready2 and rdflib packages of python. Here is how my class of concepts and predicates look.

```
from owlready2 import *

onto = get_ontology("http://localhost:7200")

with onto:   
    class x(Thing):
        pass
    class y(Thing):
        pass

with onto: 
    class z(ObjectProperty): 
        domain = [x]
        range = [y]
    class t(ObjectProperty):
        domain = [y]
        range = [z]
```

Here is how I make the ttl file.

```
onto.save(file = "nov22_vocabulary_nt", format = "ntriples")
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse("nov22_vocabulary_nt")
g.serialize(destination = "nov22_vocabulary.ttl")
```

I have imported this vocabulary graph to graphdb, so that the uri links I created would be published. However, even after importing the ttl file to graphdb, uri links are throwing an error.

I guess I am missing a step here (and maybe I should identify the content that uri link is supposed to return?) and I am very confused even after looking through GraphDB documentation and watching some stuff on W3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the error? What are you doing to produce the error?

Comment: rdflib usage looks fine, so this is an owlready2 issue.